# Codeigniter 4 possible to assign db_name(Database.php) in a variable or any other option

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, connection, codeigniter-4

We want to connect one of too many databases as a default.
as per user requriment so we want take a database name in a variable or Global variable.

we are unable to use any variable in Database.php file

so guys help me for this problem.

[view code here Codeigniter 4.0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRlNO.png)

Comment: DB name is session ?? whaat !!!!

Comment: yikes. reconsider your requirements, or better explain them here because dynamically getting a database name based on user input is scary to me.

Comment: yes session
but in codeigniter 4 this way to connection of db

https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/database/connecting.html#

Comment: Please don't post images of code

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I tried to do "weird" things like attempting to assign dynamic variables in configuration files so I'm not entirely sure if CodeIgniter supports it. However, even if it does, I would suggest using the function designed for these sort of things:

https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/database/connecting.html#connecting-with-custom-settings

```
$custom = [
            'DSN'      => '',
            'hostname' => 'localhost',
            'username' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'database' => '',
            'DBDriver' => 'MySQLi',
            'DBPrefix' => '',
            'pConnect' => false,
            'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
            'cacheOn'  => false,
            'cacheDir' => '',
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
            'swapPre'  => '',
            'encrypt'  => false,
            'compress' => false,
            'strictOn' => false,
            'failover' => [],
            'port'     => 3306,
    ];
$db = \Config\Database::connect($custom);
```

I suppose, since all else is the same except for database name you could also access the database configuration property for your default database and use `$custom = array_replace($configDb, ['database' => $_SESSION['db_name'])` to change out the database name. Obviously check that `db_name` exists and isn't empty and all that jazz. You could even put this entire logic in to a class with `db_name` as a constructor so you don't have to keep doing this all the time.

E.g. (untested):

```
namespace App\Config;

use InvalidArgumentException;

class DatabaseChooser extends \Config\Database
{

    protected $dbName;

    public function __construct(string $dbName = '')
    {
        $this->dbName = $dbName;
        $config = $this->buildArr();
        return parent::connect($config);
    }

    private function buildArr()
    {
        if (empty($this->dbName)) {
            throw InvalidArgumentException('dbName cannot be empty');
        }
        $default = $this->defaultGroup;
        if (property_exists($this, $default) && is_array($this->$default)) {
            return array_replace($this->$default, ['database' => $this->dbName]);
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Invalid configuration.');
        }
    }

}
```

---

I'm sure you've considered it, but CI4 isn't exactly production ready afaik. To be honest, I'd be using something like Laravel, Lumen, or Symfony which already have an extensive and tested codebase, as well as many compatible third party packages.

Comment: we are using Codeigniter 4 so I that version more restriction to use other variable or other things 
so you have any Idea in codeigniter 4

Comment: Apologies didn't see CI4 as the image name. Please tag CI4 next time. it is actually the same as far as I can see, just the syntax is different. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. "shown this error"